# How can I use Beautiful Soup to parse the batter's names?

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have had no issues grabbing three stats: hits, runs and rbi's. Here is the code I have been working with so far:

```
#import modules

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, os
from selenium import webdriver

#start webdriver 

os.chdir('C:\webdrivers')
header = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); options.add_argument("--start- 
maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard- 
batting.shtml')

#grab html

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()

#parse three stats: rbi's, runs and hits

hits = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'H'})]
runs = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'R'})]
rbi = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'RBI'})]

#print data

print(hits, runs, rbi)
```

The code above works great. When I try to grab the batter's names, however, I run into some problems. The batter's names are not parsed correctly. I would like just their first and last name if possible.

Here is what I tried:

```
print(soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'player'}))
```

The batter's names are in the code but there is a lot of extra data. Also, my computer slowed down a lot when I tried this line of code. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any help you may offer!

Answer (score 0):

**How to get batter's names:**

just request the player data directly, I found this url when I watch the page load, get player name from this url will very easy:
https://d3k2oh6evki4b7.cloudfront.net/short/inc/players_search_list.csv

**How to speeder your code:**

**First:** Using `selenium` to load the webdriver will cost the most part time in your code.
For your grab target, I suggest you use `requests` directly instead `selenium`

**Second:** lxml parser will speeder than the html parser, but you should install it if you never use it, just run "`pip install lxml`" will help you.
[installing-a-parser and summarizes the advantages and disadvantages of each parser library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

for example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# start requests
target_url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2018-standard-batting.shtml'
headers = {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'}

page_source = requests.get(target_url, headers=headers).text

#grab html

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')

#parse three stats: rbi's, runs and hits

hits = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'H'})]
runs = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'R'})]
rbi = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'data-stat': 'RBI'})]

#print data

print(hits, runs, rbi)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is not in source page, please refer to this link:
https://d3k2oh6evki4b7.cloudfront.net/short/inc/players_search_list.csv

this is the csv file you can directly download this file or you can fetch desired data with code as well.